# Derivatives of a the Matrix diagonal function

Tags: matrices

If A is a not diagonal but symetric matrix and diag() is a function such that returns the diagonal, i.e. diag(A) is a matrix of zeros except on the diagonal. Im interested in the derivative of vec(diag(A)) with respect to x where A is a function of the vector x. So, how do I do This in the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should clarify what "A is a function of the vector x" means. Some funcion in particular? Each component of the matrix is an indepent function of x?

Answer (score 6):

The derivative of the $(i,i)$ entry of $\text{diag}(A)$ is the same as the derivative of the $(i,i)$ entry of $A$.  The derivative of the $(i,j)$ entry of $\text{diag}(A)$ for $i \ne j$ is $0$.

Comment: @ Robert. Interesting. So you are saying $\nabla diag(A)= diag(\nabla(A))$?

Comment: Of course.  The derivatives are element-wise operations.